# Emails not being sent in Magento 1.9.3.6 - CRON Running

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, email-scheduler

Im having an issue on my site where no emails are being sent. Everything has been working fine and a few days ago emails stopped being sent.

Cron looks to be fine and running and being successful

[image]

anyone got any ideas on what i can try?

Comment: we had the same issue, it turns out the IP of the mail sending server was blocked outside of magento

Comment: This was the issue for us. All emails were being blocked on the hosting side.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else having this issue might be worth contacting your hosting. They could see quickly that they were blocking emails and got it sorted.